How should I migrate those kind of TFS folders to Git
I need to convert from TFS to Git some old project that're hosted on TFS 2010. For the main branch there's no problem since I've used successfully Git-TFS and I've everything (for now) correctly working.

My question is about those "folders" that are not automatically taken when retrieving the main
To migrate the main I've done
git-tfs clone http://SITE:8080/tfs/NAME_AAA/ "$/Project/[name of 1]" "C:\xxx\git_migrations\xxx_folder" 
But doing so it only takes Main content.
How can I get NTSSRC, Releases,and the others?
If I need to separate them since are different git repo, how should I call them in Azure Devops Repository? Something as Project1_NTSSRC and so on?

Due to the discrepancy between how TFVC and Git are working, that's the typical use case where it is difficult to migrate form TFVC to Git.
It seems that you only have one main branch to migrate.
In this case, maybe you'd better doing a "flat" migration (without branch support) to migrate the whole parent folder "disabling" the branch support of git-tfs with argument --branches=none.
That way you could migrate history of a TFVC folder. Git-tfs try to manage it as a branch.
See https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/usecases/migrate_tfs_to_git.md#fetch-all-the-history-for-just-the-main-branch-ignoring-all-the-other-branches

According to this documentation of Git-TFS tool, it seems only migrates the contents of branches. If you want to also migrate folders, you may need to change the folder to branches or move them into a branch, then you can use the tool to migrates the contents of all branches.
In addition, if your are using Azure DevOps Server 2019 or later, or Azure DevOps Services, Azure DevOps has the built-in features to Import and migrate repositories from TFVC to Git. These built-in features also only import/migrate the contents of branches.

